# How to properly wrap `useFetch` to access reactivity?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am wrapping `useFetch()`  as a composable to provide a custom baseURL and to automatically set an authentication token, but when I call the composable within a component without the `await` keyword it does not behave as expected with reactivity. Normally, I can call const `{ data, pending, status } = useFetch('...')` and the UI will update once the promise resolves and `data` is available, but with the wrapper this does not work. Seems I must always use `await` with `useCustomFetch()`

Any idea why this would not work?

Below is the custom wrapper.

```js
import type { UseFetchOptions } from 'nuxt/app'
import { defu } from 'defu'

export async function useCustomFetch<T>(url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const { data, status, getSession }: { data: any; status: any; getSession: Function } = useAuth()

  const headers: HeadersInit | undefined = {}

  // NOTE: Set 'Authorization' header
  if (data && status.value === 'authenticated') {
    const session = await getSession({ required: true })
    headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`
  }

  const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
    baseURL: config.public.baseApiUrl,
    headers,
    onResponse(_ctx) {
      // EX: _ctx.response._data = new myBusinessResponse(_ctx.response._data)
    },
    onResponseError(_ctx) {
      // TODO: Send notification to Sentry
    },
  }

  // NOTE: Deep defaults, use unjs/defu
  const params = defu(options, defaults)

  return useFetch(url, params)
}
```

In a component, this does **not** work.

```js
<script setup>
const { data, pending, status } = useCustomFetch('/resources')
</script>
```

Comment: The docs show that you need to `await` on `useFetch`'s result. Did you forget to write your `await` on `useCustomFetch`?

Comment: `useFetch` does not require `await`

Comment: await is required by the fact that [useFetch returns a Promise](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#type), and you must await a Promise for it's resolved value.  All the doc examples also use await.  By your own admission, your code doesn't work _unless_ you use await.  Are you consulting some other documentation?

Comment: `await` is not required. Try to use `useFetch` without `await` and it works. If a function returns a promise, this does not mean that it requires `await` to resolve.

Comment: See the [usage example from Nuxt's docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#usage)

Comment: @yoduh This is probably because they tried to normalize the use of useAsyncData and related composables. They still return the refs immediately, which is something you'd expect from non-nuxt asynchronous use... composable. Probably not advised without await because it's not documented and I've seen at least one post before where not using await caused a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useAsyncData` and other composables that rely on it (`useFetch` in this case) return augmented promise. `async` function always returns native promise that doesn't affect the way it works but doesn't have `data`, etc from augmented promise. In order to preserve the original behaviour, `useCustomFetch` should use raw promises and implement the augmentation.

```
function useCustomFetch<T>(url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  let promise = Promise.resolve<unknown>(null);

  if (data && status.value === 'authenticated') {
    promise = promise
      .then(() => getSession({ required: true }))
      .then(session => {
        headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`
      })
  }

  ...

  promise = promise
    .then(() => useFetch(url, params));
  Object.assign(promise, ???);

  return promise as ReturnType<(typeof useFetch)<T>;
}
```

It can be seen this approach would create a problem because no properties to augment exist when the result is immediately returned. This would require to add another level of complexity by creating new `data`, etc refs and syncing their results to the ones that `useFetch`. It's `await getSession` that makes the implementation unnecessarily complicated and potentially may result in incorrect behaviour when the composable is used without `await`.

`getSession` call should likely be moved to fetch option, then this becomes straightforward, this allows to infer the type of the result and potentially results in more correct behaviour because a request won't use stale `session` on refetch:

```
function useCustomFetch<T>(url: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  ...
 const defaults: UseFetchOptions<T> = {
   async onRequest(_ctx) {
     const session = await getSession({ required: true })
     _ctx.options.headers = {
       ..._ctx.options.headers,
       Authorization: `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`
     }
   },
  ...
  return useFetch(url, params);
}
```

Note that augmented promises and the usage without `await` aren't listed in [the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-async-data#type). Since this is not documented, this shouldn't be relied on and can change without notice.

If the request is supposed to be performed lazily with the result not being awaited, `useFetch` and thus custom composable can be used with `lazy` option:

```
await useCustomFetch(url, { lazy: true, ... })
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is it not possible to just add a single header-why do I have to spread all the headers? When I just use `options.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${session.accessToken}` the request fails.

Comment: It's a safer way to do a thing like this as options.header may or may not exist, and spread correctly handles non-object values